# How do I answer a question from a comment that doesn't relate to the original question?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, etiquette

[This innocent little answer](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/a/13503/4216) regarding fonts to pair with Helvetica generated more interest than I would've guessed. There were a few comments asking me to elaborate and a few that disputed the validity of my assertion.

Further information about the lineage of Helvetica could make for an interesting reference piece on GD.SE. And I suspect a reference to Helvetica would drive some level of search engine traffic for the site. The trouble is that I'm not sure how to go about posting it in the SE model.

Is this simply not kosher here or can I coalesce the comments into one question that I then answer myself?

Answer (score 2):

It is okay to ask questions from comments to questions. I've done this before, to great effect. Just make sure it is a worthwhile question. I would also give other people a chance to answer it, but you are allowed to answer your own question, there is even a badge for it.